# How to handle a bidirectional many-to-many relationship with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to setup a bidirectional many-to-many relationship using the same table data, namely User, I also have a link table named Userusers which joins the one user with another user, but I am not sure how to handle the bidirectional side, because the result of my code only shows one direction.

```sql
--Table User:

create table User (
    UserID          int auto_increment not null,
    UserFirstName   varchar(30) not null,
    UserSurname     varchar(30) not null,
    UserTel         char(10),
    UserCell        char(10),
    UserEmail       varchar(50) not null,
    UserPassword    varchar(50) not null,
    UserImage       varchar(50),
    UserAddress1    varchar(50),
    UserAddress2    varchar(50),
    UserTown/City   varchar(50),
    UserProvince    varchar(50),
    UserCountry     varchar(50),
    UserPostalCode  varchar(50),
    Primary key(UserID)
)

--Table Userusers:

create table UserUsers  (
    UserID          int not null,
    FriendID        int not null,
    primary key(UserID, FriendID),
    foreign key(UserID) references User(UserID),
    foreign key(FriendID) references User(UserID)
)
```

PHP code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM User u INNER JOIN UserUsers uu ON uu.UserID = u.UserID INNER JOIN User f ON f.UserID = uu.FriendID WHERE uu.UserID = " . $_SESSION['userID'];
```

Comment: give example of what kind of information you want to retreive from table

Comment: That depends on how you view the relationship; I _guess_ that: A consider B as a friend doesn't necessary mean B also consider A as a friend. If this is true, your query looks fine: find all users and all users that he/she friended.

Comment: What do you mean by one direction and both directions?

Comment: @Passerby - I want it to be so if A is friend with B then B is also friends with A.

Comment: @GordonM - When I say one direction I mean if A is friends with B, B isn't necessarily friends with A, I want them to be mutual friends

Comment: @wisdom - Lets just assume for this example I will require User1's firstname and his friend's firstname(User2's firstname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, no, your tables do show bidirectional relationships.

Consider your table UsersUsers

The column userID represents the person who is FRIENDS WITH friendID.

Say user 1 wants to be friends with user 2

Our UsersUsers table will look like:

```
UserID   |   FriendID
  1              2
```

Sure, we see that there is now a relationship between User 1 and 2, but we also see that User1 has initiated the friendship, showing the direction from 1 -> 2

Now when User2 wants to accept the friendship, we can insert another record into the table, making it:

```
UserID   |   FriendID
  1              2
  2              1
```

There's definitely some better meta data you can add to the relationship table to understand more about the relationship created, but the UserID field should be considered the `owner`, or `sender`, and the FriendID should be considered the `receiver`.

So - you already have most of the work cut out for you, now all you have to do is create your queries to act upon this bidirectional relationship.

Getting all confirmed friends for User1:

We will assume $the_logged_in_user_id = 1

`SELECT * from Users U JOIN UsersUsers F ON U.UserID = F.UserID WHERE F.FriendID = '$the_logged_in_user_id'`

That will show all the confirmed friendships for `$the_logged_in_user_id`, assuming this is what you're going for.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had everything right except for the query, made a really stupid error. Thanks